# How to install Ubuntu on the HDD, with Windows 7 ultimate on the SSD

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7, ssd

I'm a newbie on Ubuntu and up to now I use it from a permanent USB pendrive. Now I've decided to install it on my HDD.
My PC has an SSD with Windows 7 Ultimate and a standard HDD that up to now I'm using just for storage.
My intention is to keep the SSD only for windows, particionate the HDD and install Ubuntu on it.

My doubts are:

- is this solution fine or some problems can rise and make my pc unstable (both on windows and ubuntu)?
- installing two different OS on two different disks, I imagine I have to set the boot preference from BIOS. Am I right? Are there other methods to switch from one system the other without change the BIOS options every time?

If it can help you, my mobo is an Asus Mod 1150 H97-Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly safe to install Ubuntu alongside Windows on a separate hard drive. Once installed you should not have to change any BIOS settings, instead Ubuntu will now be an option available to you in the Windows Boot Loader. You'll just have to select either load Windows or load Ubuntu from a menu.

The easiest method to achieve a dual boot is to install Ubuntu from inside Windows with the Ubuntu Windows Installer (Wubi). You can download it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

For instructions on how to install Ubuntu using the installer you can read a detailed explanation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi).

Just be sure to select your HDD when you're asked where you want to install Ubuntu on this screen:

[image: Wubi installer]

One thing to note is that Wubi only allows you to install a partition with a maximum of 30gb. If you want a larger partition you will need to install Ubuntu from your live USB. This method is also safe, just be sure you've specified the correct partition to install it to and be careful not to accidentally install it on your SSD.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have some questions about it. Does wubi allow me to particionate my HDD or I must do it before running wubi? Even if I have two different OS in two different disk I have a boot menu? If yes, why this menu is not bypassed by the bios boot preference?

Comment: Wubi will partition your HDD for you, just specify which drive you want to install ubuntu to and select the size you want the partition to be. You shouldn't need to fiddle with BIOS because Ubuntu is added to the existing Windows Boot Loader. Every time your computer loads it automatically loads the Windows Boot Loader before starting Windows. Because only Windows is installed you probably never see this screen. Once Ubuntu is installed the Windows Boot Loader will notice that there are now two options and will stop to give you the choice of which OS to boot.

Answer (score 2):

### For future readers: `wubi` is deprecated.  Don't use the solution above...

Both possibilities (Using BIOS boot order/Not using BIOS) have their advantages/disadvantages.

**Using BIOS**

*Advantages*

- Windows doesn't even know that Ubuntu is there.
- Ubuntu gets an entire HDD to itself
- Easier to delete Windows once you've used a *professional* OS.  ;-)

*Disadvantages*

- You have to remember to press the button!  ;-)

**No BIOS**

*Advantages*

- Just one menu to rule them all...
- No need to hit the [F12] or whatever key on boot

*Disadvantages*

- grub2 (the Ubuntu boot loader) incorporates the Windows boot loader into its own menu and boots Windows if you choose to. *However*, if you ever do a Windows boot repair, grub2 will be gone (Microsoft wants its OS to work and doesn't care about the rest of the world especially Linux) and you'll have to do grub2 repair as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault but I don't know how can I set to use or not the bios, can you explain it? Moreover, you said "ubuntu gets an entire hdd to itself": is it true even if I particionate the hdd so I can use it only for a storege purpose any more?

Comment: If you don't know how to set the BIOS, then that solution is definitely not for you!  ;-)
If you partition the hard drive, you can use it for anything you want: storage, system, swap, temp, run, ...  I would advise 4 partitions: one for Linux swap: 4GB minimum, 2*RAM ideally, one for "/" Minimum 48GB for the Linux system, one for Linux Data (as much as you want) and then one that is for Windows *and* Linux Data...

Comment: I'm able to set the boot preferences from the bios. Probably I did not explain my point very well, you said that one can choose to use the bios or not to use the bios: how can I concretely do this choice? Do you mean that the bios option is to install ubuntu in the HDD (windows in the SSD), while the no bios option consists in installing both on the same disk (so I get the boot menu)?

Comment: I'm sorry for not making myself clear:  The BIOS option is to set the second hard drive as boot hard drive and then install Ubuntu on there and change your boot drive to the SSD when you want to boot into Window$ and change it back when you want to boot into Ubuntu again.  The non-BIOS option is not to change anything, still install on the second hard drive and use the Ubuntu Boot manager (grub2) to choose between Windows and Ubuntu...

Comment: Just to be complete: In the non-BIOS option, grub2 will be the only thing installed on your SSD by Ubuntu.  Everything else will go to the HDD.

Comment: PS, If you like this answer, press the up-arrow above the "0" next to my answer and accept this as an answer instead of WUBI (which is an additional thing that can break)
I'm now fully Ubuntu, but I ran in BIOS mode using Windows less and less until 9 months ago, when I deleted it!
(Ubuntu can have its boot manager on the SSD and still boot from the HDD, whereas Windows cannot.)